# C# Web Proxy request

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make a web proxy. Here is what I have so far:

```
    IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(sURL);
    Console.WriteLine("Resolved:{0}", IPHost.HostName);
    string[] aliases = IPHost.Aliases;
    IPAddress[] address = IPHost.AddressList;
    Console.WriteLine(address[0]);

    IPEndPoint sEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(address[0], 80);
    Socket IPsocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,   ProtocolType.Tcp);
   IPsocket.Connect(sEndpoint);
   if (IPsocket.Connected)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Socket OK");
   }   

   NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(IPsocket);
   StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);

   for (int i = 0; i &lt; lista.Count; i++)
   {
      sw.WriteLine(lista[i]);
      Console.WriteLine(lista[i]);
   }
   sw.Flush();
   string response = sr.ReadToEnd();</pre>
```

And how I read the request:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
string plusz = "";
plusz = sr.ReadLine();
while (plusz != "")
{
    lista.Add(plusz);
        plusz = sr.ReadLine();
}
return lista;
```

The request looks like this:

```
GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.12 Safari/535.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: rememberme=true; NID=54=l  
(...)
 pY
```

And as you can see I sent this exactly. The problem is that the program stops at the `sr.ReadToEnd()` method. It is just waiting for the data to arrive, but nothing happens. If I send a wrong request, then it works, so the browser displays the wrong request page (400).

Comment: you really don't need a while loop to read the response Stream.. I would suggest something like var reader = new StreamReader(pageResponse.GetResponseStream()); I will paste a working example below if you would like to see a simpler approach to creating a proxy please let me know..

Comment: Yes, please, I would like to. I have been thinking about the problem for a half day now..

Comment: keep in mind that this is a console test app so feel free to use this if it helps. I have this working for me currently.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace ProxyTester
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var htmlResponse = new StringBuilder();
        var RequestPage = BuildHttpRequest("https://google.com/");
        GetHttpResponse(RequestPage, htmlResponse);
    }

    public static HttpWebRequest BuildHttpRequest(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var getPage = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebProxy proxyHTTP = new WebProxy("201.38.194.50", 53128);


            getPage.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            getPage.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.19) Gecko/20110707 Firefox/3.6.19";
            getPage.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            getPage.Method = "GET";
            getPage.Proxy = proxyHTTP;
            getPage.Timeout = 10000;
            getPage.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
            return getPage;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static bool GetHttpResponse(HttpWebRequest page,  StringBuilder htmlResponse)
    {
        htmlResponse.Length = 0; 
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
           // var pageResponse = page.GetResponse();
            page.Timeout = 10000;
            var pageResponse = (HttpWebResponse)page.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("5 minutes!");
            if (pageResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                var reader = new StreamReader(pageResponse.GetResponseStream());
                htmlResponse.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
                pageResponse.Close();
                reader.Close();
                return true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(pageResponse.StatusCode.ToString());
            pageResponse.Close();
            return false;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Uhm, thanks, but I am not sure if this is good for me, because I don't know the url. And what should I write as a paramater when creating a WebProxy class? I would like to request a webpage exactly as the browser tells me. I hope you understand.

Comment: if you don't know the URL.. you can always refactor the code that is there to accept a param many ways to skin the allmighty cat..

Comment: alright, I tried it. It doesn't return a response either. I think something else will be the problem.

Comment: Strange, because when I turn off the proxy in Google Chrome, then it works, and it gets the response (in your code), but when I use it proxy then it doesn't work. I don't know how could I explain it more clearly.

Comment: I am wondering if there is something browser specific that the code is dealing with.. or not dealing with.. it works for me in Mozilla and IE

Comment: Alright, I found a website (i don't know if it's allowed to post links here, if not then sorry):http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/ImplementsamultithreadedWebproxyserver.htm

Would you check it for me if it works for you, and if yes, then what did you use, and how did you set it up?! I am really curious now...

Comment: the code that I posted I used exactly I the way that it is I am wondering if you are experiencing any firewall issues or security issues internally on  your end..

Comment: But then why do I get back the Wrong request page completely. I mean, when I send a wrong request it works, so it returns the 400 error page...

Comment: alright, I chaged the ReadToEnd() method to ReadLine(), and that way I could read every line (What the heck?! anyway), so I have my reponse. Now I can't send it back, and I don't know WHY?! I could read the wrong request page, and I could send it back, now I can't do the same with the good one. Ok, so here is the send method:
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s); ("s" is a networkstream)
            sw.Write(message);
            sw.Flush(); 

should I send it line by line?